# Share 3D array between threads using pThreads

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, pthreads

I am quite new in parallel programming and I am trying to parallelize an application using pThreads. I have a function that browse a 3D array, compute some things and store the result into another 3D array. The function go through the array with two for loops (the third dimension is 2).

My idea is to share the surrounding for loop (with the `i` index) between different threads. Here is the function I want to parallelize:

```
#define MAX_X 100
#define MAX_Y 100

void serialFunction(float v1[MAX_X][MAX_Y][2], float v2[MAX_X][MAX_Y][2]) {
     int i,j;
     for(i=0;i<MAX_X;i++) {
         for(j=0;j<MAX_Y;j++) {
            v2[i][j][0] = 2*v1[i][j][1];
            v2[i][j][1] = -3*v1[i][j][0];
         }
     }
}
```

I tried to make those changes:

```
struct thread_data {
  int start;
  int end;
  float ***v1;
  float ***v2;
};


void serialFunction(float v1[MAX_X][MAX_Y][2], float v2[MAX_X][MAX_Y][2]) {
   int t;
   pthread_t threads[NB_CPUS];
   int startBoundaries[NB_CPUS], endBoundaries[NB_CPUS];
   struct thread_data data[NB_CPUS];
   computeBoundaries(startBoundaries, endBoundaries);
   for(t=0;t<NB_CPUS;t++) {
      data[t].start = startBoundaries[t];
      data[t].end = endBoundaries[t];
      data[t].v1 = (float***)v1;
      data[t].v2 = (float***)v2;
      pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, threadedFunction, (void*)&data[t]);
   }
}



void *threadedFunction(void *threadArg) {
   struct thread_data *data = (struct thread_data*)threadArg;
   float ***v1 = data->v1;
   float ***v2 = data->v2;
   int i,j;

   for(i=data->start;i<data->end;i++) {
      for(j=0;j<PIC_Y;j++) {
         v2[i][j][0] = 2*v1[i][j][1];
         v2[i][j][1] = -3*v1[i][j][0];
   }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the code, I get a segmentation fault each time `threadedFunction` try to access an element of `v1`. It behaves as if `v1` would not be allocated, and I don't understand why. This happen even if `serialFunction` has not reached its end.

The constrainsts are that I cannot change `serialFunction` signature and I have to use pThreads.

Can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First and foremost, you're assuming `float v1[MAX_X][MAX_Y][2]` and `float ***` are compatible; they most-certainly are NOT. The first is a contiguous block of MAX_X*MAX_Y*2 floats. The second is a pointer to zero-or-more pointers to zero or more pointers to zero or more floats. Nowhere in this galaxy or our neighbor Andromeda are those two things remotely the same.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed this problem thanks to your comment by declaring my array as (*v1)[MAX_Y][2] in the function signature and in my structure. It now works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that you pass to the thread is created local/automatic data to the function `serialFunction()`. You pass a pointer to this data as argument to the thread function. The data is not guaranteed to exist when the function exits. Note that there nothing in your code that stops `serialFunction()` from exiting ***before*** the data gets accessed in the thread function `threadedFunction()`. If `serialFunction()` exits before the data is accessed through the pointer in `threadedFunction()`, what you get is Undefined behavior and a situation as what you encounter now.

Solution is to, either:

- Delay the exit of function `serialFunction()` by using something like `pthread_join` or
- Allocate the data on a static/global/dynamic storage to detach its lifetime from the scope of the function.

Comment: Thanks for your very quick answer! You are right, I have forgotten to join the threads. I had some other problem with my syntax concerning the pointer to the array, but it seems to work now both with the join solution and the global variable.
Thanks a lot!